# Ошибка Accessing static property App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::$table_name as non static

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно изменить имя таблицы при авторизации но я получаю ошибку **Accessing static property App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::$table_name as non static**

**AuthController.php**

```
public static $table_name = 'server_1_users';

public function findOrNewUser($info)
{
    $user = new User($this->table_name);
    $user = User::where('steam_id', $info->steamID64)->first();
}
```

**User.php**
    public $table;

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->table = AuthController::$table_name;
}
```

Comment: Ну и в `new User($this->table_name);` почему используется `$this`, если свойство статическое?

Answer (score 0):

AuthController.php

```
public static $table_name = 'server_1_users';

public function findOrNewUser($info)
{
    $user = new User(self::table_name);
    $user = User::where('steam_id', $info->steamID64)->first();
}
```

Зачем менять имя таблицы при авторизации? я бы посоветовал пересмотреть логику своего приложения.